# Filter by column doesn't work (jQuery DataTables)

Tags: jquery, datatables

If the data is static (not taken from the database), search by column work.
But, if the data retrieved from the database, search by column does not work.

My Html Code is like this :

```
                    <table id="example">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="filter_data">                     
                            <td>Hotel</td>
                            <td>City</td>
                            <td>Country</td>   
                            <td>Region </td>                            
                          </tr>
                          <tr>                         
                            <th>Hotel</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Region</th>                                                   
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#example .filter_data td').each( function () {
                var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
            } );

            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                 "language": {
                     "processing": "load data"
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "url": BASEURL + "book/get_book",
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "columnDefs": [{ 
                    'orderable': false,
                    'targets': [0,3]
                }], 
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                "columns": 
                [                            
                    { "data": "hotel", "name": "hotel" },
                    { "data": "city", "name": "city" },
                    { "data": "country", "name": "country" },
                    { "data": "region", "name": "region" },
                ]
            } );

            table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
                $( 'input', $('.filter_data td')[colIdx] ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    console.log(colIdx);
                    console.log(this.value);
                    table
                        .column( colIdx )
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                } );
            } );

    });     
</script>
```

When I search by column, it does not work

Thank you

Comment: When you made the serverside true. Then you will receive some extra parameters on the server side. And you have to filter the data based upon those value by yourself by querying the database with the provided extra parameters.

Comment: @Abhisek Malakar, Thank you very much.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar, I need your help. you try to see here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206742/server-side-datatables-with-ignited-datatables-library?noredirect=1#comment54233280_33206742). Does it modify the Ignited-Datatables Library?